# Is there a way to bind shortcut keys to switch to already open applications in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, firefox

Is there something similar to quake mode in tilix for Firefox?

I want to switch to any already running instance of firefox (or maybe open a new one if not present already) using a shortcut like <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a "native" way to assign a shortcut in order to switch to an existing window. You can achieve this using `wmctrl`. I personally use a little tool `jumpapp` at https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp, which internally also uses `wmctrl`.

**Using wmctrl**

`wmctrl` is not installed by default. Install it using `sudo apt install wmctrl`.

Following one-liner will switch to Firefox, or launch it if no Firefox window is currently open:

```
wmctrl -xa Firefox || firefox
```

In Bash shell, the command separator `||` means: if the first command was not successful, then try the next one. Thus, the first command `wmctrl` attempts to activate a window of WM_CLASS `Firefox`. Only if no such window is found, which implies Firefox is not running, the command after the separator is launched, i.e., starting the Firefox browser.

To find the WM_CLASS of a window to use in the `wmctrl` command, you can use

```
wmctrl -lx
```

The option `x` will add a column showing the window class, as in

```
0x04400003  0 Navigator.Firefox     hostname keyboard - Is there a way to bind shortcut keys to switch to already open applications in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS? - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
```

The third entry, `Navigator.Firefox` shows we can use `Firefox` (or "Navigator", or "Navigator.Firefox") as the window class to identify the window.

**Using a tool jumpapp**

While using `wmctrl` directly is not quite complicated, a tool `jumpapp`, in fact a bash script that relies in `wmctrl`, is even more simple in use, and has a few added benefits:

- It is even simpler to implement.
- If multiple windows of the same application are open, subsequent presses on your shortcut key will cycle through them.
- You can bind another shortcut key, e.g. a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Your Shortcut</kbd> to cycle windows in reverse
- You can have your hotkey toggle between bringing the window forward and minimizing it, if the app is already running.

`jumpapp` is not in the repositories, but can conveniently be installed as a .deb following the instructions on the website.

Once `jumpapp` is installed, simply precede the command to launch your application by `jumpapp` to launch your application launched if it is not running already, or switch to an existing window. Assign that command to a shortcut key.

You can also edit the `Exec=` line in a `.desktop` file, to provide the same functionality to a launcher. As a matter of fact, a command `jumpappify-desktop-entry` is included that will do that automatically for a .desktop file you specify.

Launchers in Gnome Shell already behave like this by default, but in other desktops, the app can be used to provide similar "launch or switch-to" functionality to launchers.

Comment: What advantage does jumpapp offer over `wmctrl`?

Comment: This works! Thank you :D

Comment: @DKBose Convenience. Just a "jumpapp gnome-terminal" rather than having to brew your own little script.

Comment: In Kubuntu, I have keyboard shortcuts like `wmctrl -xa Kate || kate`, `wmctrl -xa Konsole || konsole`, `wmctrl -xa Dolphin || LANG=en_GB.utf8 dolphin`, `wmctrl -xa Geany || geany`, `wmctrl -xa Firefox || firefox`, `wmctrl -xa google-chrome || google-chrome-stable --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode --profile-directory=Default --start-maximized`, etc.

Comment: Indeed also very simple and fully adequate for assigning a shortcut. However, you need to correctly identify the Window class, so this is another slight advantage of jumpapp..As I mentioned wmctrl, I can also add this f to be more complete.

Comment: @DKBose My edit now includes a few advantages of jumpapp, which, in scripting, would be more complex to implement.

Comment: Re. `xprop | grep WM_CLASS`, you can use `wmctrl` itself. Usually, `wmctrl -l` is enough. But, for some cases, `wmctrl -lx` is needed.

Comment: @DKBose I was looking to do it with wmctrl, but I overlooked the -x option. Of course, it is more convenient here to just also use wmctrl.

Answer (score 0):

require:

- xdotool

Create script for terminals /home/user/term.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=$@

xdotool search "term$n"

if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
   xdotool search "term$n" windowactivate
   exit
fi

xfce4-terminal --initial-title term$n
```

bind to keys

- Alt-1 : /home/user/term.sh 1
- Alt-2 : /home/user/term.sh 2
- Alt-3 : /home/user/term.sh 3

Create script for firefox /home/user/firefox.sh:

```
xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox"

if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
   xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox" windowactivate
   exit
fi

firefox
```

- Alt-4 : /home/user/firefox.sh

Comment: subsequent presses on your shortcut key will cycle through them